# my node.js application is using redislabs instead of heroku-redis

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have installed the add-on heroku-redis and have followed the heroku-redis docs and changed my node.js code to use heroku-redis but my application still uses redis labs when i was developing my application on my laptop. I am now deployed to heroku but i can not get my coide to use heroku-redis.

I get this error message in my heroku logs.

```
2016-09-28T13:08:03.884652+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Redis connection to redis-18680.c8.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com failed - connect ENOENT redis-18680.c8.us-east-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com
```

My heroku-redis is setup correctly becaus i have this in my logs:

```
2016-09-28T13:08:57+00:00 app[heroku-redis]: source=HEROKU_REDIS_RED sample#active-connections=1 sample#load-avg-1m=0.135 sample#load-avg-5m=0.09 sample#load-avg-15m=0.075 sample#read-iops=0 sample#write-iops=0 sample#memory-total=15664876.0kB sample#memory-free=13947600.0kB sample#memory-cached=541184kB sample#memory-redis=289144bytes sample#hit-rate=1 sample#evicted-keys=0
```

My environment var is setup to be HEROKU_REDIS_RED_URL
`redis://h:p9kdcrn0v82f0h2u1jf7ubi6elb@ec2-54-163-233-146.compute-1.amazonaws.com:xxxxx` where xxxx is my port, this was created by Heroku when i installed the redis addon.

And this is how I am creating my redis client in node.js

```
var client = require('redis').createClient(process.env.HEROKU_REDIS_RED_URL);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.